# excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas how to stop calculating?

Tags: microsoft-excel

excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas how to stop calculating?

Is there a way to delete the formula so it stops trying to calculate?

Comment: turn your calculations to manual then go find and delete the formulas

Comment: You should add information about which Version of Excel you are using and The operating system.  We can't give a specific solution without knowing what software you are using.  Its also best to include exact error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are NOT using office 365 and on a windows machine I can offer this advice.

Open run (windows button on keyboard + R)
Start excel in safe mode (type excel /safe)
Find the formula and deleted or modify it, 
save it as a different name (to be safe)
Exit Excel (Alt + F4)
Open file and see if issue is resolved.

Alternatively you can enter safe mode on some versions of excel by holding the CTRL button then starting excel.